# inotify fails to react on IN_DELETE

Tags: c, inotify

I have the following (crude) function, which continually watches a directory for new files and files being deleted, recording such changes. It correctly records all new files and directories, but doesn't seem to react at all to files or directories being deleted.

It appears to be the `read()` call which doesn't return as it should when files are being deleted, though it does for files being created.

The function is being called as one of two independent threads, though at present the other thread doesn't do anything (just an empty, infinite loop as a placeholder).

```
void* watchfs(void* arg) {
    int infp, watch, length, i ;
    char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN] ;
    struct inotify_event* event ;

    if ((infp = inotify_init()) < 0) {
        fatal("inotify: Could not initialize") ;
    }

    watch = inotify_add_watch(infp, userdir, IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE) ;

    for (;;) {
        length = read(infp, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN) ;
        if (length < 0) {
            fatal("inotify: Could not read events") ;
        }

        i = 0 ;
        while (i < length) {
            event = (struct inotify_event*) &buffer[i] ;

            if (event->len) {
                if (event->mask & IN_CREATE) {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR) {
                        record(LOG_FILESYS, "New directory created") ;
                    } else {
                        record(LOG_FILESYS, "New file created") ;
                    }
                } else if (event->mask & IN_DELETE) {
                    if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR) {
                        record(LOG_FILESYS, "Directory deleted") ;
                    } else {
                        record(LOG_FILESYS, "File deleted") ;
                    }
                }
            }

            i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len ;
        }
    }

    inotify_rm_watch(infp, watch) ;
    close(infp) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figured out what is going on. Linux, or perhaps Gnome, doesn't actually delete files but simply moves them around. Even when a file is simply renamed it is apparently moved somewhere, then a new file with the new name is moved into the folder from somewhere else (a temp folder somewhere?). The `rm` command actually deletes a file and my code registers that as an `IN_DELETE` event as expected. Deleting files or directories in Gnome however registers as `IN_MOVED_TO`, while renaming registers as `IN_MOVED_TO` followed by `IN_MOVED_FROM`.

I thought I had checked for this as one of the first things, but clearly not well enough.

Comment: That's your linux distro(ubuntu?) and your file manager playing hob behind the scenes. To emulate windows recycle bin, they have a recycle bin folder set up, and map delete to the mv command. The stuff gets moved to the recycle bin and compressed, instead of deleted.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun Ubuntu, yes. That's the conclusion I've come to as well. Though I'm not sure exactly what goes on during a renaming. A copy with a new name is made somewhere, it seems, then the file with the old name is moved to the trash, and the copy with the new name is moved to the actual destination folder. Seems very wasteful to me.

Comment: On linux, renaming is the same as moving within the same directory. So if I have a file `/my/home/file` and rename to `/my/home/superfile`, it will register as `moved /my/home/file to /my/home/superfile`. There are two events because you may be interested in watching `/my/home/file` or `/my/home/superfile`. The moved to event is linked to `file` and moved from is linked to `superfile`. If you only had the moved to event, then programs watching `superfile` would not receive an event.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun Ah, that makes a lot more sense. I should have known that. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: No problem, I didn't figure it out until I went looking for a rename command on an older box. You can't find it, because they didn't have one. The modern rename command only really exists for regular expression renames across multiple files. For single renames, mv works like a charm.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue thanks very much for this. I actualy get `IN_MOVED_FROM` on delete in Ubuntu, do you get the same? You said in your post that you got `IN_MOVED_TO` on delete on gnome, is this a typo? Is there anyway to identify if the `IN_MOVED_FROM` is of a delete? Is waiting 1sec after receiving a `IN_MOVED_FROM` to see if a `IN_MOVED_TO` happens the only way? Because unfortunately a cookie exists on `IN_MOVED_FROM` triggered on the deleted file in Ubuntu :( I was hoping to maybe test if got `IN_MOVED_FROM` and `cookie` is `0` then it's a delete :(